# Shaper Helix | Use different layouts on different pages

Tags: css, templates, joomla, module

I'm using the Shaper Helix plugin, I've customized my Layout via Template Manager.

Is it possible to use two different Layouts on varying pages of my Joomla setup?

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (it refers to collapsible module positions ). Read tip 4 http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/8-tips-and-techniques-for-modifying-joomla-templates--webdesign-4344